# ajax form submit without redirect dosent work

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I am trying to submit a form using ajax.

Without the ajax, the form action 'send.php' works fine, it sends an email with data from the form (including files etc...)

But I want it to do so without redirecting to the php page,
so I try to use ajax but the php is not executed (I think), it should send an email and the email is not sent (reminder - without ajax it works fine).

The ajax alert "Form submitted" (success) but the mail is not sent and non of the echo/alert in the php file shows up...

HTML form:

```
<form  method="post" action="send.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"id="myForm" target="_blank">
```

ajax:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#myForm', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({            
            url: $('#myForm').prop('action'),
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#gif').css('visibility', 'visible');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#gif').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                alert('Form submitted'); 
            },
            error: function() {
                // The request failed - So something here
                alert('Form NOT submitted'); //display an alert whether the form is
            }
        });
    });
```

Edit:
Found the source of the problem, my ajax is not complete I need to make use of FormData!

I can't find how to make use of it for all the files in my form can someone please show an example for the right ajax?

Comment: Please show your send.php code

Comment: show us your code which is written in send.php file

Comment: What is the error from the server? Look at the network request in the console and see what is being returned.

Comment: by the way im using PHPMailer to send the mail and when the command $mail->send() is executed it shows all the process(like log) and thats my main goal prevent the user from seeing that..

Comment: You can find the output of the php script in the `data` variable. As you don't use that, how do you know that none of the `echo`'s show up? Also note that you cannot upload files with ajax like this, you'd need a `FormData` object to do that. So anything related to the uploads will fail right now.

Comment: thanx for  your comments, 
-jeroen : one problem at a time, ill keep that in mind.
– epascarello : i think there is no error if it alert succes.

Comment: In success make the `alert(data)` you will see what you get back or do a `console.log(data);` and check the console using F12. Lastly, did you updated your file to `json_decode` the form data your get? We meed to see that to help any.

Comment: i used alert(data) and noticed that it shows check array exist failed, so it does related to the files!! thanx   -nerdlyist you helped making some progress!! im seraching for how to use FormData , any links?

Answer (score 0):

create a variable in your JavaScript like

```
var myData = $('#form_ID').serialize();
```

and then when making ajax call use

```
 $.ajax({
        url: URL_HERE,
        method: "POST",
        data: myData,
        success: function (results) {
```

it will submit the form data, simple is that.

Comment: i maneged to solve it but thanx anyway. btw your solution is good for all the inputs but not for  files included, atlist it dident work in my case.